# Compare contents of two string arrays, and remove strings which occur in both

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops, string-comparison

This is for a project program, I have been unable to solve this problem for a while, and am hoping someone can point out the problem with my code that I am missing. The goal of this code is to compare two sets of arrays( A and B ) and to create a third array which consists only of entries which only occurred in B.
My approach to this was to initialize the third array and fill it each entry with "".  From there the two given arrays are compared and if an entry in B does not occur in A, then that entry is added to this third array.  However when I test what I have written, array B is copied into the third array exactly as is, no entries are removed.
Here is the code I have.
From looking through the code with my puny human brain, I feel like this should work, however it does not.
If String A contains "computer"
and String B contains "computer", "are", "you"
String C should be  "are", "you"
yet running this code, String C comes out to be "computer", "are", "you"

```
   public static String [] findPatternInSentence( String [] A, String [] B) {
        if (A== null){
            return null;
        }
        String[] C= new String[A.length+1];
            for (int p = 0; p <  A.length+1; p++){
            C[p]= "";
                    }

                for( int i = 0; i< B.length; i++){
                int k = Eliza.inList(A[0], B);
                  if(k > -1){
                    int j = 0;
                if(A[j].equals(B[i]) && j < A.length-1){
                        j++;
                }
                else {

                    C[j] = C[j] + " " + B[i];
                }
            }
            if (k == -1)
            {
                return null;
            }  
        }
        return C;
    }
```

Comment: did you check my answer? if it didnt help I'll going to remove it

Answer (score 0):

For example, say your arrays contain

```
String[] arr1 = {"a","b","c"};
String[] arr2 = {"a","b","c","d"};
```

Utilizing sets..

```
// add everything from arr2
Set set = new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(arr2)); // ["a","b","c","d"]

// remove everything that showed up in arr1
set.removeAll(Arrays.asList(arr1)); // ["d"]
```

If you can't use sets and want an array-based approach (utilizing maps) and care about frequencies instead of just if an element appears which you haven't mentioned in your post..

```
 String[] arr1 = {"a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a"};
 String[] arr2 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"};

 int totalElems = 0;

 Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

 // add stuff from arr2
 for(String _b: arr2) {
     totalElems++;
     if(!freq.containsKey(_b)) 
         freq.put(_b, 0);
    freq.put(_b, freq.get(_b)+1); 
 }

 // add stuff from arr1, removing stuff that were in arr2
 for(String _a: arr1) {
     if(freq.containsKey(_a) && freq.get(_a) > 0) {
         totalElems--;
         freq.put(_a, freq.get(_a)-1); 
     }
 }

 String[] c = new String[totalElems];
 int ptr = 0;
 for(String key: freq.keySet()) {
     int count = freq.get(key);
     while(count != 0) {
         c[ptr++] = key;
         count--;
     }
 }
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c)); // [b, c, d, d, d]
```

And if you simply care for elements B that did not appear in A..

```
 String[] arr1 = {"a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a"};
 String[] arr2 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"};

 int totalElems = 0;

 Map<String, Boolean> freq = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

 // add stuff from arr2
 for(String _b: arr2) {
     if(!freq.containsKey(_b)) {
         totalElems++;
         freq.put(_b, true);
     } 
 }

 // add stuff from arr1, removing stuff that were in arr2
 for(String _a: arr1) {
     if(freq.containsKey(_a) && freq.get(_a)) {
         totalElems--;
         freq.put(_a, false); 
     }
 }

 String[] c = new String[totalElems];
 int ptr = 0;
 for(String key: freq.keySet()) {
     if(freq.get(key))
         c[ptr++] = key;
 }
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));  // [d]
```

Based on what I have written, it should cover most possible cases. Let me know if you need further help. If you can't use `Maps`, only way I see is to go through all elements of `array A` for every element of `array B`, given the info provided.

I'll just add that too.. This implementation should work (I haven't tested it)

```
String[] c = new String[b.length];
int cPtr = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < b.length ; i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < a.length ; j++) {
        if(a[j].equals(b[i])) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found)
        c[cPtr++] = b[i];
}
```

Comment: It does, however I am not allowed to use sets  (this is for a project, I probably should have said that in the original post, sorry).  The goal is to use sets of loops and switches to fill array C.

Comment: @UVB-76 Sure thing. It would be good if you mark the answer correct, so that future users can find answers faster.